# Is there a way to password protect Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I would like to create a check request form but I only want users who either enter a password or whose Google accounts I give permission, to be able to fill out the form. Is this possible?

One idea if this isn't by default would be to embed the form in a web page that is password protected and then never hand out the URL of the form but I am hoping there is something better than that available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to password a protect a form within Google Docs at the moment.

Comment: Does that mean, that everyone with access to the Internet could find my Form and fill in the questions and submit their reply?

Comment: It would be very hard to just stumble upon your form if you haven't made the URL public somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Google Docs account then you also have access to Google sites. Create a Google Sites page and embed your form on it, then set the page permissions to private and enter those email addresses for the people you want to give access to. If they have a Google account, they can log in under their username. If not, they'll have to create an account first.

Comment: Sure comes close.

Answer (score 5):

I've just adapted some trick which is very simple by using Validation option in Text field to check the password which you set it before give it away. For example.

1. Set a field with user name let them choose from the list you add their name in advance
2. let connect those name the pagebreak which is on their name
3. on the page let set a text field and add the pass word to the option in Validation section specify that with Equal (=) only So, if the password they key in is not the same that person can't pass through your form

p.s. Don't forget to mark x in Required Question check box otherwise that person can pass through your form

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I like how simple this solution is (and it still seems to technically work, nearly eight years after!). However, at the time of writing this, the password is visible in the page source, so this solution may not be secure enough for all applications.